# How do I print an array in Java's jdb debugger?

Tags: java, debugging, jdb

How do I print out the values of the byte array all at once? I seem to recall I could specify a memory range in gdb. Is similar functionality is available in jdb?

I have a Java byte array:

```
byte [] decompressed = new byte[OUTPUT_FILE_IO_BUFFER_SIZE];
```

which I populate from a String:

```
System.arraycopy(decompressedString.getBytes(), 0, decompressed, 0, 
                         decompressedString.length());
```

In jdb, I want to print the contents of the byte array. I tried

```
main[1] print decompressed
```

which returns:

```
 decompressed = instance of byte[7] (id=342)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution:

```
dump decompressed
```

This dumps the byte values! :)

Comment: it's printing them as signed integers -- is there any way to get it to print hex values?

Local variables:
prefix = instance of byte[16] (id=2384)

Main Thread[1] dump prefix
 prefix = {
-118, -113, -73, -125, 13, -42, -63, 87, -10, 54, -122, 57, -63, 3, 81, 116
}